# swift - tableView found nil while unwrapping

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 `UIViewController`: `MainViewController` -> `CreateNewViewController`.

`tableView` is contained in `MainViewController`. I have connected `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `tableView` to `MainViewController`. I have also connected an outlet to `MainViewController`.

In `CreateNewViewController`, I would have this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _ = MainViewController.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil, createNewViewController: self)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Init in `MainViewController` would initialize the delegate property:

```
init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?, createNewViewController : CreateNewViewController) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    createNewViewController.createNewCallBack = self
}
```

I am trying to update the `tableView` with the protocol func. I do not understand why `tableView` would be `nil` when it comes back from `CreateNewViewController`. This is the callback function:

```
func addNewBook(book: Book) {
    self.books.append(book)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you using a storyboard?

Comment: Yes, I use storyboard for both

Comment: I was using segue from Main to CreateNew

Comment: @ChongJenFoong We can't acess outlet of one class into another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, you have a segue going from MainVC to CreateNewVC.

In the `viewDidLoad` of CreateNewVC, you seem to be attempting to set the delegate of CreateNewVC to MainVC. However, this is not the correct way to do it.

You should do this *before* presenting `CreateNewVC`, in the `prepareForSegue` method of MainVC.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? CreateNewViewController {
        vc.createNewCallback = self
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks! I am new to swift and your answer certainly help me so much in initializing property using prepare segue in the future

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set the delegate in the wrong place.
According to the documentation about the prepare method:

> The default implementation of this method does nothing. Subclasses
>   override this method and use it to configure the new view controller
>   prior to it being displayed. The segue object contains information
>   about the transition, including references to both view controllers
>   that are involved.

You have to implements this method:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let myViewController = segue.destination as? CreateNewViewController {
        myViewController.createNewCallback = self //this set the delegate
    }
}
```